# object doesn't support this property or method createDocumentFragment in IE 8 Windowns XP SP2

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer

When I load my WordPress web site in IE8 on Windowns XP SP2. Having errors:

> Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
>   line: 4
>   char : 24165 
>   URI: .../wp-include/js/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2

I don't know how to solve this bug. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

According to [JQuery](http://jquery.com/browser-support/), they support IE 6+, but there is a note on the linked page:

> While jQuery might run without major issues in older browser versions,
>   we do not actively test jQuery in them and generally do not fix bugs
>   that may appear in them.
>
> Similarly, jQuery does not fix bugs in pre-release versions of
>   browsers, such as beta or dev releases. If you find a bug with jQuery
>   in a pre-release of a browser, you should report the bug to the
>   browser vendor.

Also, I would update to SP3 if you can. SP2 is very old at this point, and causes a lot of incompatibility issues.